# Авторизация на сервере с помощью python

Tags: python, сервер, авторизация

Допустим у меня есть сервер x.com.

При попытке зайти на него у меня требуют логин и пароль (как при подключении через FTP в браузере — не путать с авторизацией на САЙТЕ, это авторизация для доступа к СЕРВЕРУ).

Какой-либо информации для авторизации python в таком сервере я не нашёл.
Можете помочь, потому что единственное что я нашёл это авторизация через HTTP.

Хелпаните пж

Comment: используй библиотеку requests и будет тебе счастье

Comment: В каком плане авторизация для доступа к серверу через сайт?

Comment: В браузере появляется уведомление с требованием логина и пароля как при подключении через ftp в браузере

Comment: Ответы помещайте в ответы, а не в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В библиотеке requests действительно можно авторизоваться для доступа к сайту.

Пример:

```
req = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'password'))
```